# Detecting cursor in a certain range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out a way to detect where the cursor is in a certain range. This would be the sort of thing I'm looking for:

```
if ('bla bla bla' && Input.mousePosition == (in between x1 and x2, in between y1. and y2))
```

Is this possible in unity, because I can't figure it out :(
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also you can use `Rect.Contains` for Prevent dublication:

```
var InRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width/2, Screen.height).Contains(Input.mousePosition);

UnityEngine.Debug.Log(InRect);
```

Comment: Is the 0,0 the coords of the middle of the rect or a corner?

Comment: Also, instead of using screen width and height as the size of the rectangle, can I set 4 numbers, 2 for x and 2 for y e.g.
(0, 0, 100, 200, 100, 200)

Comment: One more thing, can I use it in an if statement like this:
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) && (inRect)

Comment: Hi, (0 and 0) refers to the corner of the page. use the `Screen` like top for finding center range if you want. for second question Of course, you can use any function that returns `float` or `int` in params, and your third question is correct. `InRect` returns true when the mouse is in the frame otherwise false, and you can use it in any other condition for saving time.

Comment: hi again. (x1, y1, width, height) is true. that means: x2 = x1 + width, y2 = y1 + height, for more info (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect-ctor.html)

Comment: If you define the variable outside the method, it is necessary to use `Rect` instead of `var`. you're welcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244528/discussion-between-towerofgray11-and-kiynl).

Answer (score 3):

```
Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
```

This returns a `Vector2` with the coordinates `x` and `y` of the mouse position. To check if this point with the coordinates `mousePos.x` and `mousePos.y` lies in the range `x1` and `x2`; `y1` and `y2`, we can write

```
if((mousePos.x >= x1 && mousePos.x <= x2) &&
   (mousePos.y >= y1 && mousePos.y <= y2))
{
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively,

```
if(mousePos >= new Vector2(x1, y1) &&
   mousePos <= new Vector2(x2, y2))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Where should I put my mousePos variable, because when I put it in my script, it comes up with an error saying:
UnityException: get_mousePosition is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'PlayerMovement' on game object 'champ'.

Comment: initialize it just above the if statement, or instead of declaring, you can directly write Input.mousePosition.x and Input.mousePosition.y